# Import font with special (danish) characters to xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

When I try to import a custom font to xCode, I can not get the special Danish and Swedish characters imported. The font file is .otf. All "Normal" english characters are imported correct. Is there some trick that must be used when importing a font with special characters like: "æÆøØåÅ"?

Comment: These are all unicode characters right?

Comment: Yes, full list of characters we can not import: æÆøØåÅöÖäÄ

Comment: Please write what you did already